# How we get a single value of mongodb using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have to try to print the value of my MongoDB in the console. But it gives me undefined in my console I had done a lot of things to get the result but all is vain
I want to print number single field value (min_score) in console or browser from MongoDB using node js code

1). This is my node js code

```
   this.levelChange = function(req, res, next){

    try{

        var arr = [];
        var query = {'level_num':1};
        QuizLevel.find(query,function(err,data){
            var a = parseInt(arr.push(data));
            console.log(a.min_score);
        });
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error");
        return next(err);
    }
};
return this;
```

2). This is my js level schema

```
   {
     _id:{type:String},
     age:{type:Number},
     level_num:{type:Number},
     min_score:{type:Number},
     max_questions:{type:Number}
     }
```

3). This is my json value

```
     {
     "age":5,
      "level_num":1,
     "min_score":10,
     "max_questions":30
     }
    {
     "age":5,
     "level_num":2,
     "min_score":12,
     "max_questions":33
     }
     {
     "age":5,
     "level_num":3,
     "min_score":15,
     "max_questions":35
      }
```

4). This is the result in console

```
 [undefind]
```

I want to get the result min_score 10 in my console

Comment: `arr.push()` does not return what you think it does.

Comment: sir how I retrieve that value

Comment: min_score from mongodb using node js

Answer (score 2):

if data is the output like this:

```
 {
     "age":5,
      "level_num":1,
     "min_score":10,
     "max_questions":30
     }
```

Then you can simply use data.min_score and output will be : 10

var a = parseInt(arr.push(data)); will gives you the a as 1 so a.min_score will be undefined definitely.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Instead of `var a = parseInt(arr.push(data));` You need to destructure the array and then use data.min_score

```
QuizLevel.find(query,function(err,data){
        const [a] = data
        console.log(a.min_score);
    })
```